# How can I calculate age in a MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to implement a procedure within mysql that returns the age based on a calculation.
The date of birth (DATE) is passed in and then the calculation is done. Should be relatively straight forward but I cannot seem to get it to work. I am not sure if this is an appropriate situation for a "select statement" and
I apologize if this is extremely simple but this is my first run at procedures.

If somebody could please tell me what I am doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S. I have a table called "PERSON" that contains the field "age" (int) which is currently empty until the stored procedure is called.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE determineAge(IN birthDate DATE)
BEGIN
DECLARE today TIMESTAMP; 
SELECT DATEDIFF(today,birthdate)/365 AS ageInYears
FROM PERSON;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

call determineAge('June 25, 1981');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works.  No need to declare "today" - just use a `NOW()` function in your query.

Also, no need to select `FROM` anything... you're just querying a single value.

Your date was formatted wrong (MySQL requires `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, and you want to floor the difference to get a whole number of years.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE determineAge(IN birthDate DATE)
BEGIN
    SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(birthdate))/365);
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL determineAge('1981-06-25');
```

Finally, you could theoretically return the year value as an `OUT` param if you wanted to, though a query result is just fine.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE determineAge(IN birthDate DATE, OUT age INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(birthdate))/365) INTO age;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

There you go!

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Will accept! Out of curiustiy, do you mind showing how an OUT param would work in this case? Thanks again

Comment: Done.  Added the `OUT` param example at the bottom.

Comment: `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthdate, NOW());` should work as well, and it's more readable.

Comment: @TheSmose Thanks again. one last question, is this valid? age= DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(birthdate))/365?

Comment: Alex, you would have to use `SET age = ...`

Comment: @therefromhere - Good point.  That's a much simpler way of calculating age.  I was trying to work with the OP's code.